# Google Sheets - hide column(s) based on row 1 value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bunch of content on a google sheet organised by columns. I want a script that will check row 1 from cell 4 to 100 to see if the letter X appears. If the letter X appears then the script should hide that column.

And then also the reverse of that being unhide all columns regardless of row 1 content. I have found this snippet of code(s) but they don't seem to really do anything, there is no failure displayed or error, just doesn't hide the column(s)

```
function hideColumn() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get first sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // get data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn()+1;

  Logger.log(lastCol);

  // iterate over columns
  for(var i=1; i<lastCol; i++) {
     if(data.getCell(1, i).getValue() == 'x') {
        sheet.hideColumns(i);
     }
  }
}

function showColumn() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get first sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // get data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange();
  
}
```

I have managed to code the same actions in Excel directly and they work exactly as I want them as per codes below, however, google doesn't like the command button or code when I upload the .XLSM file  to Google Drive and run as a Sheet.... Any ideas? Excel Code below that works well

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 4 To 30
If Worksheets("Current Orders").Cells(1, i).Value = "x" Then
Worksheets("Current Orders").Columns(i).Hidden = True
End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
For i = 4 To 30
Worksheets("Current Orders").Columns(i).Hidden = False
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can do this with a [`TextFinder`.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)*

#### Code Example:

```js
function hideColumnsWithx() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var cells = sheet.createTextFinder("x").matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  
  cells.map(x => sheet.hideColumns(x.getColumn()));  
}
```

**Rundown of this function:**

- Get the first sheet from the Active Spreadsheet
- Find all cell ranges which contain exactly the string "x"
- Hide every column that is returned from the `TextFinder` using `array.map()`

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder - matchEntireCell(Boolean) | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchEntireCell(Boolean))
- [Class Sheet - hideColumns(columnIndex | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex)
- [Class Range - getColumn() | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getColumn())
- [Array.prototype.map() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: That works great, Can the script be adapted to only look for the X value in one Row and not across the whole spreadsheet, also can it pick a specific named Spreadsheet within the Doc?

And finally is there a code that would unhide all the columns... ? I cant get that piece to work as well.... The Hide part works like dream!!

Comment: Apologies, 
}
i tried on a blank sample and it worked well there, but on the live spreadsheet where my real data is, the script doesnt do anything?

Comment: @HariKara it can be, but it is out of scope of the original question so you should pose this as a new question. Stackoverflow is a question-answer forum where each individual problem should be tackled as a different question. You can ask a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: why does your script not work on the actual spreadsheet but works on a blank new spreadsheet?

I am putting the X's in the first row for each column but the script doesnt hide the columns?

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: @rafa_guillermo Please see below link to Sanitised Google Sheet.... 

The hidden script is loaded and should be fired based on the press of the blue circle in Row 1

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AX_mOS5Ms3gNrNClY32lK4K9Rtu9RJbnaH76NgpZBoM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, I unhid columns D and E and then ran the script and it hid them again. Can you please explain what is not working? Have you made sure to authorise the script?

Comment: So on teh copy doc I sent over that had the sanitisation it runs... When I run the script with teh same button and the same script, it says script finished but columns are not unhidden... very odd behaviour. 

I can send a screen share to show you over zoom if you are free?

Comment: Are you looking to have the columns unhidden when clicked a second time?

Comment: If that works then that would be great, but I cant get the columns to hide on teh non sanitised Spreadsheet. If you want I can screenshare to show you...

Comment: Would this help?  Take your non sanitsed sheet, and make a copy.  In that copy do a copy-and-paste-special-values-only for the whole sheet, then delete all of the sensitive data - if necessaary, use a data filter to exclude rows with an "X" - does the script still fail in that copy?  If so, you should be able to share that with us.  Make a fresh copy to erase any version history, which would still have the sensitive data.  LEt me know if any of this doesn't make sense.